# Sqlite and python between not returning value

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to implement a select on my DB, but every time that a put datetime.now() as arg, it doesn't return the list.

Sqlite3 command:

```
if from_date is not None and to_date is not None:
                ping_select = """
                    select valor
                    from dispatcher_storage
                    where timestamp between ? and ? and chave = ?
                """
                self.data_base_conn.execute(ping_select, (from_date, to_date, key))
                sql_time_history = self.data_base_conn.fetchall()

            self.sqliteConnection.commit()
```

the part of code in other module is:

```
ping_histogram = Dispatcher().fetch_all("provider_ping", date_past, datetime.now())
```

But, I'm not getting see the problem, when I put `None` in place of `datetime.now()` the code work and I get the values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify that the format of `datetime.now()` match with the format of your database. What is the format of your database, because Sqlite don't have and specific datetime format.